# Что значит thread safe / non thread safe и какой выбирать при скачивании php?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте друзья, подскажите ответы на след. вопросы:

1. В чём отличие thread safe от non thread safe в php и какой лучше качать (ОС windows, если это имеет значение). Возможно вопрос глупый, но для меня это действительно не понятно(
2. Если качать последнюю версию php то достаточно ли для неё
   документации?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/index.php - документация всегда актуальна.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`thread safe` - потокобезопасный

`non thread safe` - соответственно, не потокобезопасный

Если будете настраивать PHP как FastCGI модуль(т.е. запуск для обработки каждого запроса нового экземпляра PHP), то потокобезопасность не нужна - выбирайте NTS, так как оно будет работать быстрее.

Если же будете настраивать как `mod_php` (например под Apache), то потокобезопасность необходима.

PS также некоторые расширения требуют потокобезопасной версии. На вскидку не вспомню какие, но точно были. Читайте документацию по необходимым расширениям.

Comment: Корректно ли будет работать скрипты и коды с разной серверной составляющей (Apache, FastCGI)? Или нужно что-то типа API?